# Is it possible to use source maps with Traceur used directly from the page?

Tags: javascript, traceur

I have a small static project written in ES6. It's compiled with Traceur dynamically every reload (for development purposes):

```
<script src="lib/traceur/traceur.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/traceur/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script>
  traceur.options.experimental = true;
  traceur.options.sourceMaps = true;
</script>

<!-- my ES6 code goes here -->
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

The contents of `bootstrap.js` are rather simple:

```
new traceur.WebPageTranscoder(document.location.href).run();
```

Now, I can't get the source maps to work (Chrome 34). The manual suggests the file should be compiled offline and served with appropriate header, but that's precisely what I was trying to avoid.

**Is there a way to get source maps to work entirely from the client side?**

Comment: Still no comment and no answer ?

Comment: You are doing everything client side... Could you provide the code you are using to generate the source maps?

Comment: @Centijo they are generated from insides of Traceur, and I have no idea how it works internally TBH.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it personally but https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-module-loader looks like it might be what your looking for.

Comment: Hm, on paper it looks interesting. I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
traceur.options.sourceMaps = 'inline';
```

https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/SourceMaps